# Calculating conditional probability for student network example

Tags: probability, bayesian

[image: Network]

based on the https://djsaunde.github.io/read/books/pdfs/probabilistic%20graphical%20models.pdf at page 91

It claims that $P(l^1 | i^0)$ is 0.389. However, I am unable to get this value or something close to it.

For this i am summing up $i^0$ rows.
$P(g^1, i^0) = (0.3 + 0.05)/2 = 0.175$
$P(g^2, i^0) = (0.4 + 0.25)/2 = 0.375$
$P(g^3, i^0) = (0.3 + 0.7)/2 = 0.5$

$P(L^1 | i^0) = 0.9 * 0.175 + 0.6 * 0.375 + 0.01 * 0.5 = 0.3425$

Subsequently it also claims that $P(i^1 | g^3)$ ~ 0.079 which i am unable to derive this answer also.

I am new to probability so can someone explain why is this the answer to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First expression to calculate is:
$$p(l^1|i^0)=\sum_{g\in\{g^1,g^2,g^3\}} p(l^1|g)p(g|i^0)$$

You've $p(l^1|g)$ as a table, so $p(g|i^0)$ needs to be plugged in for each $g$.

For $g=g^1$:

$$p(g^1|i^0)=\sum_{d\in\{d_0,d_1\}} p(g^1|d,i^0)p(d)=0.3\times0.6+0.05\times0.4=0.2$$

Following this way, I could verify the result, and I believe you can, too.

Beware that the tables are conditional probabilities and you need to account for priors as well (not just *mean* the two probabilities as you did in your calculations).

Comment: Can you explain your first expression @gunes

Comment: It's the total probability law. We'll have $p(l|g,i)=p(l|g)$ because of the conditional independence imposed by the network itself (based on the graph)